# Give Id from the maximum value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a query like below,

```
Select max(Mkey) from p_leave_allocation
```

which gives me `max(Mkey)` as `1643`.

Now I want to insert into another table say `p_leave_allocation_11122015` whose `mkey` should start from `1644`

what will be the query then ?

**UPDATE**

I will be inserting data like this

```
INSERT INTO p_leave_allocation_11122015(Mkey, Entry_Sr_no, Comp_mkey,FDepartment_Id,FModule_Id,Year, Emp_mkey, Emp_card_no, U_Datetime, Delete_Flag,Month12)SELECT Mkey,Entry_Sr_no, Comp_mkey,FDepartment_Id,FModule_Id,Year,Emp_mkey,Emp_card_no,U_Datetime,Delete_Flag,Month12FROM p_leave_allocation
```

I am using `sql-server-2005`

Comment: This sounds like reinvenitng `IDENTITY`

Comment: @lad2025: yes but in different `table`

Comment: So add IDENTTY column with `IDENTITY(1644,1)` or if it exists use `DBCC CHECKIDENT ( table_name, RESEED, 1644 )`

Comment: @lad2025: Like this `INSERT INTO p_leave_allocation_11122015(Mkey) Identity(1641,1)` ??

Comment: if it's a `select`, you can use `row_numer() over()` + `your_max_id`

Comment: @coder No I mean you need to change table structure with `ALTER TABLE`

Comment: @lad2025: can you let me know the steps, because. I will also be taking data from the old table. This is what i will do 

`INSERT INTO p_leave_allocation_11122015(Mkey, Entry_Sr_no, Comp_mkey,FDepartment_Id,FModule_Id,Year, Emp_mkey, Emp_card_no, U_Datetime, Delete_Flag,Month12)
SELECT Mkey,Entry_Sr_no, Comp_mkey,FDepartment_Id,FModule_Id,Year,Emp_mkey,Emp_card_no,U_Datetime,Delete_Flag,Month12
FROM p_leave_allocation`

Comment: Share both tables CREATE scripts

Comment: @lad2025 how to share, the structure is a bit long ?

Comment: Only first few columns + PK

Comment: There is no primary key as such `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[p_leave_allocation](
 [Mkey] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
 [Entry_Sr_no] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,`

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[p_leave_allocation_11122015](
 [Mkey] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
 [Entry_Sr_no] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97611/discussion-between-coder-and-lad2025).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the suggestion to add IDENTITIY to your table you could try it like this:

The ROW_NUMBER() will bring up a row counter starting with 1. If you add your max value, you "create" the running IDs on the fly...

```
INSERT INTO p_leave_allocation_11122015(Mkey, Entry_Sr_no, Comp_mkey,FDepartment_Id,FModule_Id,Year, Emp_mkey, Emp_card_no, U_Datetime, Delete_Flag,Month12)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY p_leave_allocation.MKey) + 1643
      ,Entry_Sr_no, Comp_mkey,FDepartment_Id,FModule_Id,Year,Emp_mkey,Emp_card_no,U_Datetime,Delete_Flag,Month12
FROM p_leave_allocation
```

EDIT: If you do not want to write the max value you can put the appropriate `(SELECT MAX(MKey) FROM Somewhere)` statement there too (in brackets)...

Comment: thanks for this, also one thing for `3`, `4` columns i just need to add values  as `0` so what should I do in this case ?

Comment: Not like that, for some columns, I just need to insert values as `0`

Comment: @coder, Maybe I do not understand... Just replace the column name in the select-part with the value you want to insert (instead of the column's value)...

Comment: So it will insert for all the rows. Right ??

Comment: @coder, yes something like `INSERT INTO aTable(ID, SomeText, AnotherText) SELECT ID,'hello',AnotherText FROM AnotherTable` will insert the column's value from ID and AnotherText, but will write "hello" into all "SomeText"...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97612/discussion-between-coder-and-shnugo).